# JSON error : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

what is the error here :

```
.done(function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse( data );
                if(json['status'] === "success"){
                    //some processing
                }
                else {
                    alert( "error 2" );
                }
            })
```

I got the error message on:  var json JSON.parse('('+data+')')

data is returned from a php script :

```
/*...............*/
$sql->execute();
$i = 0;
while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){
    $response["affiliates"][i]["affiliate_name"] = $result["coupon_name"];
    $response["affiliates"][i]["affiliate_id"] = $result["coupon_id"];
    $i++;
}
$response["status"] = "success";
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: It's probable data isn't some JSON...

Comment: Why are you adding () around it? not {}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the spec for JSON (easily understood version here: http://json.org/). There is nowhere that says that parenthesis are valid. `({"foo": true})`, for example will never parse. It may be `eval`ed as it is valid javascript, but javascript is not JSON.

Comment: I still get : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Then try console.logging out the data. See what it looks like. Does the data match the spec?

Comment: data is a php array encoded to json using json_encode($myarray)

Comment: That's obviously not all it is, otherwise you wouldn't be getting the error. I can read the code you wrote. What is the server response. The FULL server response. And if you're using jQuery, are you sure jQuery isn't autoconverting the data for you.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's wrong.

"(1)" (for example) is not a valid JSON string.  Why are you pasting those parens on at all?

Comment: I took them off but stii getting : SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Well, at least you've advanced a bit.  Open the URL directly in your browser and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

JSON format only use curly and squared braces. You shouldn't append parentheses.